# Connecting mysql to lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

```py
import pymysql

def con(event=None, context=None):
    conn = pymysql.connect(user="", passwd="",host="pvt IP of ec2", port=3306,database="dbname")
    print(conn)
```

I have replaced all the parametres with what I am using but still it is giving a connection timeout error

Comment: Hostname looks invalid.

Comment: Your EC2 host is probably blocking the connection due to security group rules. Open up the EC2 security group on port 3306 from the client IP/network.

Answer (score 1):

1. Place the Lambda function in the same VPC as the EC2 instance
2. Assign a security group to the Lambda function
3. Add a rule to the EC2 instance's security group, allowing inbound access from the Lambda function's security group on port `3306`

Answer (score 0):

I use ssl_disabled, also make sure the lambda function runs under the VCP/subnet/securitygroup so it can reach your DB server:

```
    import mysql.connector
    import os
.
.
.
        mainCon = mysql.connector.connect(
                           user=os.environ['DB_USER'], 
                           password=os.environ['DB_PASS'],
                           host=os.environ['DB_HOST'],
                           database=os.environ['DB_NAME'],
                           ssl_disabled=True
        )
```